# How to get url with unmatched string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want a URL which does not include a particular string like admin and which does not have a trailing slash(/)

For example following are  the URLs having sub string **admin**

```
  1. http://www.domain.com/admin/abc/def
  2. http://www.domain.com/admin/
  3. http://www.domain.com/admin
  4. http://www.domain.com/slug-1/
  5. http://www.domain.com/slug-1/slug-2/
```

are not matched with regex.

Following are the some examples of URLs which should be matched :

```
 1.http://www.domain.com/slug-1
 2.http://www.domain.com/slug-1/slug-2
 3.http://www.domain.com/slug-slug1/slug-2/slug-3
```

This Rule checks if a slash is not at the end 
        **^(.*[^/])$**

Comment: Do you work in unix, windows, vim, emacs, notepad... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Perl` (`file.txt` contains your URL's, one per line):

```
# Regex: (admin|.*\/$) with negation
perl -ne "print unless /(admin|.*\/$)/" file.txt

# Regex: ^((?!admin).)*((?!\/).)$ without negation.
perl -ne 'print if /^((?!admin).)*((?!\/).)$/' file.txt
```

Output:

```
http://www.domain.com/slug-1
http://www.domain.com/slug-1/slug-2
http://www.domain.com/slug-slug1/slug-2/slug-3
```

Comment: @surinderpal - are you using Perl or another language?

Comment: I need to apply this regex to redirect in .htaccess file. For example RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R]. It will put a trailing slash to every URL

Comment: Okay, so you should note this in your question. From the `regex` tag wiki: `Different languages have different regex implementations. So it's wise to mention the language in which you want your regex to work.`.

Comment: @surinderpal - I've added valid tags to your question. Additionally, try the second regex from my updated answer: `^((?!admin).)*((?!\/).)$`. It works in Perl, I'm not sure about mod-rewrite in Apache.

Comment: Well its working for the given set of patterens.But when I applied it in ,htaccess file with following rule : RewriteRule ^((?!admin).)*((?!\/).)$ /$1/ [L,R] while hitting to http://localhost then it redirect to http://localhost/e/ but it must redirect to http://localhost/

Answer (score 0):

If you use Unix/Linux:

```
cat yourfile | grep -Ev "/admin" | grep -Ev "/$"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this

```
Cat FileName|grep -v admin
```